# Getting SOL balance via api for an address

Tags: address, balance, api, solscan

I'm trying to just get the SOL balance, but I get returned a full list of tokens.

https://public-api.solscan.io/account/tokens?account=34qHtfUqxgsnTDewwoXEXuhknymJ1sqoXD7H38aKADEw

I'm using solscan public api's. But should I be using something else to get SOL balance of an address?

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark this as answered. Thank you https://solana.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 5):

You can use Solana JSON RPC API by calling `getBalance` request [example](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getbalance)

Or `@solana/web3.js` using `connection.getBalance` [example](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getBalance)

Comment: i want to do it without installing a library. mainly want to just fetch this info from an REST api call using curl.

Comment: Yeah already told you the way to do it. `You can use Solana JSON RPC API by calling getBalance request example` :)

Comment: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getbalance

Comment: `curl http://localhost:8899 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {"jsonrpc":"2.0", "id":1, "method":"getBalance", "params":["83astBRguLMdt2h5U1Tpdq5tjFoJ6noeGwaY3mDLVcri"]}
'`

Comment: I'm trying to do it with: https://public-api.solscan.io --- i don't want to install anything on my server or local.

Comment: I think SOL balance could be here https://public-api.solscan.io/docs/#/Account/get_account__account_, see "lamports", but how to know the precision this is the question)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shyft's `get_balance` REST API, to get the sol balance of any account address on Solana:

https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/18419720/UzQvt5Kf#76235c33-1f0e-4724-ad09-ed46d1da7323

Here is the link to the documentation:
https://docs.shyft.to/start-hacking/wallet#get-balance.